# Don’t scroll on a canvas to draw

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, html5-canvas, drawing

I have a webpage to learn draw and add but I have a problem, when I use this in a Desktop browser it’s ok, but when use It in a mobile browser, I can’t draw because my page do scroll. I need that the mobile browser won’t do scroll when draw in the canvas. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried using an ontouchstart event on the canvas that adds overflow: hidden; to the body element to stop scrolling? You would want to remove it ontouchend. You would also need to provide an area for the user to scroll outside of the canvas.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I change the canvas for a new canvas with angular